# liferea / webkit: GTK coilor theme ignored after minor version upgrade

Tags: gtk, gtk3, webkit

I am using `liferea` on Debian 10.

After executing regular upgrade of these 2 packages:

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

2 packages have been upgraded to newer version:

```
libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37, libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18
```

and that resulted in following libraries changed:

```
-/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18.17.14
+/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18.18.5

-/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37.49.10
+/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37.53.2

-/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/webkit2gtk-4.0/injected-bundle/libwebkit2gtkinjectedbundle.so
+/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/webkit2gtk-4.0/injected-bundle/libwebkit2gtkinjectedbundle.so
```

And since this upgrade, `liferea` suddenly ignores my GTK color theme. The preview of the feed which used to be dark color theme is now default white background

I assume something changed in the GTK profile.

What GTK attriburte has changed between these versions, and what do i have to change in my GTK theme, so that I get my light-text-on-dark-background back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in latest liferea update 1.12.6-1 on debian 10